# How to send a variable argument to the format function?

Tags: excel, vba, format, arguments

In Excel VBA, I want to format some strings with 2 digits and others with 3 (only knowing at run-time which I want to use). This can be done using the format function, e.g., Format(number, "0.00") or Format(number, "0.000"). But the function ignores the argument between quotation marks when sent as a string argument. Does anybody know what variable type to use here for the argument and provide an example? Thanks so much, I tried everthing I can think of (double quotation marks etc.), but this specific problem is not covered on any website.

Comment: Don't enclose the argument in quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks for the fast help BigBen, it now works for me. I don't know why it didn't work before honestly but I must have made some other silly mistake and then started to think that the quotation marks should be somehow part of the formatting argument.